# Why does PowerShell interpret kind/kubectl STDOUT as STDERR and How to Prevent it?

Tags: powershell, stdout, kubectl, stderr, kind

We are moving our `DevOps` pipelines to a new cluster and while at it, we bumped into a weird behavior when calling `kind` with `PowerShell`. This applies to `kubectl` also.

The below should be taken only as a repro, not a real world application. In other words, I'm not looking to fix the below code but I am searching for an explanation why the error happens:

```
curl.exe -Lo kind-windows-amd64.exe https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/dl/v0.10.0/kind-windows-amd64
Move-Item .\kind-windows-amd64.exe c:\temp\kind.exe -Force

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { iex "$args" } -ArgumentList c:\temp\kind.exe, get, clusters
$job | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Now, if I directly execute the `c:\temp\kind.exe get clusters` command in the PowerShell window, the error won't happen:

[image]

In other words, why does PowerShell (any version) consider the `STDOUT` of `kind/kubectl` as `STDERR`? And how can I prevent this from happening?

There must be an environmental factor to it as the same exact code runs fine in one system while on another it throws an error...

Comment: The `No kind clusters found` from `kind.exe` is in `STDERR` in both described calls. Try running the latter **from an open `cmd.exe` window** as `2>NUL c:\temp\kind.exe get clusters` . It's just not coloured…

Comment: @JosefZ I don't get it. Why does `kind` produce `STDERR` for just about anything? I mean, I get red error message and a stack trace from `PowerShell` when I create cluster with message `Creating cluster "kind" ...` and when I delete a cluster with error message `Deleting cluster "kind" ...`. Surely these should be `STDOUT`, no? Do I really need to `2>&1` every time I call `kind`?

Comment: I think this works as intended as `kind` will output everything on `STDERR`. Have you considered omitting those messages and running `kind` with `-q`/`--quiet` - `silence all stderr output`? I'd reckon you could also reach out for more reference on the `kind` github page:  https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind

Comment: @DawidKruk well, I have already written a PowerShell module to deal with the situation. All in all it it seems PowerShell error handling is kind of a mess: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583

Comment: @JaniHyytiäinen glad that you've managed to find the solution. I encourage you to post an answer with the module that you've created so the community could benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

- [`kind`](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) outputs its status messages to *stderr*, which in the context of PowerShell *jobs* surface via PowerShell's *error* output stream, which makes them print in *red* (and susceptible to `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` and `-ErrorAction Stop`).
- Either:

  - *Silence* stderr: Use `2>$null` as a general mechanism or, as [David Kruk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12257134/dawid-kruk) suggests, use a program-specific option to achieve the same effect, which in the case of `kind` is [`-q` (`--quiet`)](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/blob/b6bc112522651d98c81823df56b7afa511459a3b/cmd/kind/app/main.go#L60)
  - *Re-route* stderr output through PowerShell's *success output stream*, merged with stdout output, using `*>&1`.

    - Caveat: The original output sequencing between stdout and stderr lines is not necessarily maintained on output.
- Also, if you want to know whether the external program reported failure or success, you need to include the value of the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode), which contains the most recently executed external program's process *exit code*, in the job's output (the exit code is the only reliably success/failure indicator - not the presence or absence of stderr output).

A simplified example with `*>&1` (for Windows; on Unix-like platforms, replace `cmd` and `/c` with `sh` and `-c`):

```sh
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  param($exe)
  & $exe $args *>&1
  $LASTEXITCODE  # Also output the process exit code.
} -ArgumentList cmd, /c, 'echo data1; echo status >&2; echo data2'
$job | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

---

**As many utilities do, `kind` apparently reports *status* messages *via stderr*.**

- Given that stdout is for *data*, it makes sense to use the only other available output stream, stderr, for anything that *isn't data*, so as to prevent pollution of the data output. The upshot is that stderr output doesn't necessarily indicate actual *errors* (success vs. failure should solely be inferred from an external program's process *exit code*).
- PowerShell (for its own commands only) commendably has a more diverse system of output streams, documented in the conceptual [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) help topic, allowing you to report status messages via `Write-Verbose`, for instance.

**PowerShell maps an external program's output streams to its own streams as follows:**

- ***Stdout*** output:

  - Stdout output is mapped to PowerShell's *success output stream* (the stream with number `1`, analogous to how stdout can be referred to in `cmd.exe` and POSIX-compatible shells), allowing it to be captured in a variable (`$output = ...`) or redirected to a file (`> output.txt`) or sent through the pipeline to another command.
- ***Stderr*** output:

  - **In local, foreground processing in a console (terminal), stderr is by default *not mapped at all*, and is passed through to the *display*** (*not* colored in red) - unless a `2>` redirection is used, which allows you to suppress stderr output (`2>$null`) or to send it to a file (`2>errs.txt`)

    - This is appropriate, because PowerShell cannot and should not assume that stderr output represents actual *errors*, whereas PowerShell's error stream is meant to be used for errors *exclusively*.
  - **Unfortunately, as of PowerShell 7.2, in the context of PowerShell [jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs) (created with [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) or [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob)) and [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) (e.g., in [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) `-ComputerName ...` calls), stderr output *is* mapped to PowerShell's error stream** (the stream with number `2`, analogous to how stdout can be referred to in `cmd.exe` and POSIX-compatible shells).

    - **Caveat**: This means that if `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` is in effect or `-ErrorAction Stop` is passed to `Receive-Job` or `Invoke-Command`, for instance, any stderr output from external programs will trigger a script-terminating error - even with stderr output comprising status messages only. Due to a bug in PowerShell 7.1 and below this can also happen in local, foreground invocation *if a `2>` redirection is used*.

The **upshot**:

- **To *silence* stderr output**, apply `2>$null` - either at the *source* (inside the job or remote command), or on the *receiving end*.
- **To route stderr output (all streams) *via the success output stream / stdout***, i.e. to *merge all streams*, use `*>&1`

  - To prevent the stderr lines from printing in *red* (when originating from jobs or remote commands), apply this redirection *at the source* - which also guards against side effects from `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` / `-ErrorAction Stop` on the caller side.
  - **Note**: If you merge all streams with `*>&1`, the order in which stdout and stderr lines are output is *not* guaranteed to reflect the original output order, as of PowerShell 7.2.
  - If needed, PowerShell still allows you to later separate the output lines based on whether they originated from stdout or stderr - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68106198/45375).