# Powershell: stdout and stderr to separate files, without new lines

Tags: powershell, io-redirection, trailing-newline

I'm trying to store the stdout and stderr outputs of a command to two separate files. I'm doing this like so:

```
powershell.exe @_cmd 2>"stderr.txt" >"stdout.txt"
```

Where `$_cmd` is an arbitrary string command.

This works, but the output files have newlines appended after the output. I'd like to modify this to eliminate the newlines. I know you can use `cmd | Out-File ... -NoNewline` or `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText(..., [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII)`, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this with the stderr output.

**EDIT:** I've realized that the issue isn't the trailing new line specifically (although I still want to remove it), but the fact that I need the output file to be UTF-8 encoded. The trailing new line is not a valid UTF-8 character apparently, which is what's causing me grief. Perhaps there's a way to capture the stderr and stdout to separate variables, and then use `Out-File -Encoding utf8`?

Comment: You should look into `Start-Process` and the `-RedirectStandardError` and `-RedirectStandardOutput` parameters.

Comment: You only want a _trailing_ newline removed from the resulting files?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician It looks like `Start-Process` only takes a file input, not a raw command string? I need it to take a string.
@mklement0 Yes, just the trailing newline.

Comment: @mklement0 to clarify, I need it to be a UTF-8 encoded file. It seems that the final newline that it appends is not a valid UTF-8 character.

Comment: This might be a dumb question but, what is the reason of executing the commands with `powershell.exe -c` and not call `@_cmd` in a ps script with a `try` `catch` block?

Comment: In _Windows PowerShell_, `>` produces "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) files by default, whereas PowerShell (Core) 7+ uses BOM-less UTF-8 consistently. In Windows PowerShell 5.1 (and also in PowerShell (Core)) you can change the default encoding via `$PSDefaultParameterValues`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51847431/45375). However, note that `>` in PowerShell never passes raw byte output through, it is always subject to decoding into .NET strings first (based on `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, and re-encoding on output to a file.

Comment: Good point, @SantiagoSquarzon; if this is being called _from PowerShell_, there is no need to use the (Windows) PowerShell CLI, `powershell.exe`, and `& $_cmd[0] $_cmd[1..($_cmd.Count-1)]  2>"stderr.txt" >"stdout.txt"` should do.

Comment: @mkelement0 yes, the powershell.exe is unnecessary. Changing it to the suggested format doesn't solve the core UTF-8 encoding issue though.

Comment: The solution to that is in my previous comment and its linked answer. @TheMadTechnician's [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) approach is also an option, especially if you want _BOM-less_ UTF-8 files in Windows PowerShell.

Comment: P.S. Either way you'll have to trim a trailing newline from the files' content after the fact.

Comment: @mklement0 What's the tangible difference between `@_cmd` and `$_cmd[0] $_cmd[1..($_cmd.Count-1)]`? I'm not overly familiar with splatting.

Comment: @Jordan, `@_cmd` is for splatting _arguments_ being passed to a _command_ (executable), but splatting doesn't support including the command in the array, which must always be specified separately, explicitly, such as `$_cmd[0]` in this case, which - as a variable-based command - in turn requires `&` for invocation. You don't strictly need splatting for calls to _external programs_, where a regular array - such as `$_cmd[1..($_cmd.Count-1)]` - will do, and, conversely, for actual splatting you may only use a (`@`-prefixed) _variable name_, not an _expression_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TheMadTechnician's comment held the answer that worked.

```
$process = Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "$_cmd" -Wait -PassThru -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardError "stderr.txt" -RedirectStandardOutput "stdout.txt"
$exitcode = $process.ExitCode
```

Answer (score 1):

Your own **[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)**-based [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68104255/45375) that uses **`-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardError`** indeed creates **(BOM-less) UTF-8-encoded output files**, but note that they too **invariably have a trailing newline**.

However, **you do *not* need `Start-Process`**, as **you can make PowerShell's [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection), `>` produce UTF-8 files (also with a trailing newline) too**.

The following examples use a sample `cmd.exe` call that produces both stdout and stderr output.

- In ***PowerShell (Core) v6+***, no extra effort is needed, because **`>` produces (BOM-less) UTF-8 files** *by default* (a default that is used consistently; if you want UTF-8 *with a BOM*, you can use the technique detailed for Windows PowerShell below, but with value `'utf8bom'`):

  ```sh
  cmd /c 'echo hü & dir c:\nosuch' 2>stderr.txt >stdout.txt
  ```
- In ***Windows PowerShell***, **`>` produces UTF-16LE ("Unicode") by default**, but **in version 5.1** you can **(temporarily) reconfigure it use UTF-8 instead, albeit invariably *with a BOM***; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51847431/45375) for details; another caveat is that the *first* stderr line captured in the file will be formatted "noisily", like a PowerShell error:

  ```sh
  # Windows PowerShell v5.1:
  # Make `>` and its effective alias, Out-File, use UTF-8 with a BOM in the
  # remainder of the session.
  # Save and restore any previous value if you want to scope the behavior
  # to select commands only.
  $PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'

  cmd /c 'echo hü & dir c:\nosuch' 2>stderr.txt >stdout.txt
  ```

**Caveat**:

- **Whenever PowerShell processes an *external program*'s output, it invariably *decodes* it into .NET strings first**. Any external program is assumed to produce output based on the character encoding stored in **`[Console]::OutputEncoding`**, which defaults to the system's active OEM code page. This works as expected with `cmd.exe`, but there are other console applications that use different encodings - notably `node.exe` (Node.js) and `python`, which use UTF-8 and the system's active *ANSI* code page, respectively - in which case `[Console]::OutputEncoding` must be set to that encoding first; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58438716/45375) for more information.

---

As for **your statements and questions**:

> The trailing new line is not a valid UTF-8 character apparently

PowerShell's `>` operator and file-output cmdlets apply their character encoding *consistently*, so the trailing newline's encoding is always consistent with that of the other characters in the file.

Most likely it was the UTF-16LE ("Unicode") encoding used by Windows PowerShell by the default that was the true problem, and you may have only noticed it with respect to the newline.

> **Perhaps there's a way to capture the stderr and stdout to separate variables**

***Stdout* can be captured by a simple variable assignment**, which captures multiple output lines as an *array* of strings:

```sh
$stdout = cmd /c 'echo hü & dir c:\nosuch'
```

**You cannot *separately* capture *stderr* output, but you can *merge* stderr into stdout with `2>&1` and even later separate the streams' respective output lines again**, based on their data types: stdout lines are always *strings*, whereas stderr lines are always [`[ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances:

```sh
# Note the 2>&1 redirection.
$stdoutAndErr = cmd /c 'echo hü & dir c:\nosuch' 2>&1

# If desired, you can split the captured output into stdout and stderr output.
# The [string[]] cast converts the [ErrorRecord] instances to strings too.
$stdout, [string[]] $stderr = $stdoutAndErr.Where({ $_ -is [string] }, 'Split')

# Now $stdout is the array of stdout lines, and $stderr the array of stderr lines.
# If desired, you could write them to files *without a trailing newline* as follows:
$stdout -join [Environment]::NewLine | Set-Content -NoNewLine -Encoding utf8 stdout.txt
$stderr -join [Environment]::NewLine | Set-Content -NoNewLine -Encoding utf8 stderr.txt
```

**You can also apply these techniques to *PowerShell-native* commands** (and you can even merge *all* other streams that PowerShell supports into the success output stream, PowerShell's analog to stdout, with `*>&1`).

However, **if a given PowerShell-native command is a *cmdlet* / *advanced* script or function**, the **more convenient alternative** is to use the [common **`-OutVariable`** parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#outvariable) (for success-stream output) and [common **`-ErrorVariable`** parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#errorvariable) (for error-stream output).