# How to save powershell hyper-v errors to file

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I am making a script to turn virtual machines on and off in hyper-v.
Sometimes the Stop-VM command fails and I need to save the bug or reflect it in some way in a log file

I tried putting the command in a trycath but it didn't work.

Command:

```
Stop-VM $VMapagar
```

Sometimes the command gives me this error and does not turn off the machine

```
Stop-VM: Could not stop.
```

I would like to be able to reflect the failure in some way in a log.txt
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **[Scepticalist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68131089/45375) shows how to capture a *terminating* error**, by using  the [common `-ErrorAction` (`-ea`) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#erroraction) with value `'Stop'` in order to promote *non-terminating* errors (the most common kind) to *terminating* ones, which allows them to be trapped with a [`try`/ `catch` / `finally` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally).

  - Note that this approach **limits you to capturing the *first* non-terminating error** (whereas a single cmdlet call may emit *multiple* ones), because it - thanks to `-ErrorAction Stop` - then **instantly terminates the statement** and transfers control the `catch` block (where the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) reflects the triggering error in the form of an [`[ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instance).
  - Also note that execution *continues* after a  `catch` block by default - unless you explicitly use [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw) to re-throw the terminating error (or use a statement such as [`exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Keywords#exit) to exit the script).
- **To capture - potentially *multiple* - *non-terminating* errors** you have two options:

  - **Redirect them *directly to a file***, using the [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) operator `>` with the number of the error stream, `2`:

    - `Stop-Vm $vms 2>errs.txt`
    - This sends any errors *quietly* to file `errs.txt`; that is, you won't see them in the console. If no errors occur, an empty file is created.
    - Note: This technique is the only option for directly redirecting an *external program*'s errors (stderr output); however, using redirection `2>&1` you can capture success output (stdout) and errors (stderr) *combined*, and split them by their source stream later - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68106198/45375).
  - **Use the [common `-ErrorVariable` (`-ev`) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#errorvariable) to collect any non-terminating errors in a *variable*** - note that the target variable must be specified *without* the `$`:

    - `Stop-Vm $vms -ErrorVariable errs`
    - By default, the errors are still output *as well* and therefore print to the console (host) by default, but you can add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to prevent that. *Caveat*: Do *not* use `-ErrorAction Ignore`, as that will categorically suppress errors and prevent their collection.
    - You can then inspect the `$errs` array (list), which is empty if no errors occurred and otherwise contains one or more  [`[ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances, and send the collected errors to a file on demand; e.g.:

      - `if ($errs) { $errs > errs.txt }`

---

See also:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375) for information about PowerShell's two fundamental error types.
- [GitHub docs issue #1583](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583) for a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's surprisingly complex error handling.

Answer (score 3):

Use Try..Catch to trap the error by telling PS to treat it as a terminating error, then process it as you require:

```
# Rest of your script
Try {
    # Run your command, but tell PS to stop if it find an error
    # You can explore the effects of the other possible values for -ErrorAction in PS documentation.
    Stop-VM $VMpagar -ErrorAction Stop
    # If it's got this far, then there can't have been an error so write a success message to console
    Write-Host "OK"
}
Catch {
    # This code will process if there was an error in the "Try" block
    # By default, within the "Catch" block, the "$_" variable contains the error message
    Write-Host "Error: $_"
    # Write the error to a log file - "`n" tells PS to write a newline before the subsequent text
    Add-Content -Path 'c:\temp\log.txt' -Value "`n$_"
    # You could stop the script here using "Throw" or "Exit" commands if you want the whole script to stop on ANY error
}
# Your script will continue from this point if you haven't stopped it
```