# How to capture warnings to a log

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I have a script to manage hyper-v virtual machines. When I execute the command to shut down a machine, I need the warning to be saved in the log if it is shut down.

The script I have only captures the errors, I need to get both errors and warnings:

```
Try {
    Stop-VM $Machine -ErrorAction Stop
} Catch {
    Write-Host "Error: $_"
    Add-Content -Path $Log -Value "`n$_"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add `$WarningPreference = 'Stop'` at the top of your script or use `-WarningAction Stop`, this way warnings will be treated as terminating error.

Comment: You can even throw in a `-WarningVariable Warning`, and evaluate against that with an `if` statement: `if($Warning){ add-content -value $Warning`. Could do the same for errors

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Stop-VM` issues *non*-terminating errors:

```
Stop-VM $Machine *> output.log
```

Note: This redirects *all* of PowerShell's [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) to file `output.log`, including *success* output, if any, and it would work with passing an *array* of VM names in `$Machine`.

As [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) points out, you can *selectively* capture (some of the) output streams, in *variables*, using the the [common `-WarningVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#warningvariable) as well as [`-ErrorVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#errorvariable), which you can later send to a file as needed. Note that using these variables still produces the original stream output, but you can silence that with `-WarningAction SilentlyContinue` and `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. See the answer linked below for details.

---

As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, you could extend your original approach by adding `-WarningAction Stop`, but the limitation, as
explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68131787/45375), is that only the *first* error or warning emitted by the call is then captured, and, perhaps more importantly, the command is *terminated* at that point - even if *multiple* VMs were specified.

Comment: Understood, @SantiagoSquarzon, but the - perhaps not obvious (amended a bit now) - point of my answer is that you don't need a loop for cmdlets that have _array_-valued parameters: they typically emit _non_-terminating errors and warnings, which a redirection /  use of `-*Variable` common parameters can _all_ capture.