# youtube-dl process hangs with RedirectStandardOutput

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-7.0

Trying to write a basic Powershell script that will pull videos from URLs, and cut them with FFmpeg if desired.

One thing I need to do up front is pull the download options from the site to see if I want to use `-f best` or `-f bestvideo+bestaudio`. So I need to run `youtube-dl -F [url]` and return the output, but I can't seem to do so without hanging:

```
param(
  [string]$url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njX2bu-_Vw4"
)

$YTDLinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$YTDLinfo.FileName = "youtube-dl"
$YTDLinfo.RedirectStandardError = $false
$YTDLinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$YTDLinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$YTDLinfo.Arguments = "-F $url"
$YTDL = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$YTDL.StartInfo = $YTDLinfo
$YTDL.Start() | Out-Null
$YTDL.WaitForExit()

$YTDLStdOut = $YTDL.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().split([Environment]::NewLine)

Write-Host $YTDLStdOut
```

If I change `$YTDLinfo.RedirectStandardOutput` to `$false` it works and returns the output directly into the console, but I need the output in a variable. Also worth mentioning that if I run the above but without passing the process any arguments (`$YTDLinfo.Arguments = ""`) it also works, even with `$YTDLinfo.RedirectStandardOutput` set to `$true`, and just returns some youtube-dl jargon about how it needs a url.

A bit confusing to explain, but it only hangs when both redirecting the standard output and providing it with `-F [url]`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your *immediate* problem is that you're waiting for the process to exit *without ensuring that you've fully consumed its redirected stdout output first***.

That is, **your `.WaitForExit()` call may wait indefinitely**, namely if the process creates more than one output buffer's worth of stdout data, which *blocks* the process until more data is read by the caller.

Therefore, call `$YTDL.StandardOuput.ReadToEnd()` *before* `$YTDL.WaitForExit()`.

---

However, it's worth **taking a step back**:

**In order to execute *console applications* (such as `youtube-dl`) from PowerShell**, *synchronously*, with their stdout and stderr streams connected to the equivalent [PowerShell output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection), **invoke them *directly*, as you would in any shell**:

```
# Directly captures youtube-dl's stdout output as an *array of lines*.
$YTDLStdOut = youtube-dl -F $url
```

Use redirection `2>` in order to capture *stderr* output in a *file*.

Alternatively, use `2>&1` to capture stdout and stderr *merged* in a variable, and differentiate which output line came from what stream later: `-is [string]` implies *stdout* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68106198/45375).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35980675/45375) for a comprehensive overview of capturing stdout and stderr via direct invocation of console programs.

Specifically, **the following techniques should generally be avoided** for invoking console applications:

- **Do *not* use `Start-Process`** (except in unusual scenarios) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375).

  - `Start-Process` is essentially a PowerShell-friendly wrapper around the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process)  .NET API that you're using.
  - For guidance on when use of `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate, see [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239).
- **Do *not* use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression)**, which should be avoided in general - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).